# Como fazer login de aplicação desktop via aplicação web?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, login

Tenho uma aplicação web desenvolvida com ASP.NET MVC e faço o login armazenando os dados na Session.

Tenho uma outra aplicação, porém desktop, que efetua algumas tarefas que não podem ser feitas na web, porém esta aplicação precisa ser autenticada com o mesmo usuário e senha da aplicação web.

Existe uma forma de fazer a autenticação da aplicação desktop utilizando o login ativo da aplicação web?

Comment: Você vai precisar usar um webservice para isso. Você já tem noção disso? Sem mais detalhes a pergunta pode ser considerada como muito ampla, de qualquer forma é uma pergunta interessante +1. Aliás, comente quando editar a pergunta e me mencione, talvez eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Você quer usar os mesmos dados de um usuário já logado, no caso os dados da Session, ou quer utilizar o mesmo login e senha?

Comment: @jbueno Sim, já tenho noção de webservices, porém utilizo pelo Visual Studio e fazendo um WebMethod no meu controller da aplicação web, não tive sucesso. Na verdade não consegui pensar na lógica de como os dados serão fornecidos à aplicação desktop C# sabendo que provavelmente eu terei mais de um usuário logado no sistema ao mesmo tempo...isso me deixou meio confuso.

Comment: @Randrade eu quero usar os mesmos dados do usuário já logado para evitar que o usuário tenha que efetuar o login na aplicação desktop também. Basicamente é a mesma aplicação, mas tem coisas que não vou conseguir fazer pela web e que com desktop é mais tranquilo, como por exemplo acessar a Certificate Store do Windows para utilizar os certificados digitais para operações com notas fiscais nos webservices da SEFAZ. Já tentei várias coisas, mas com o fim das applet próximo os limites da web para acessar os recursos da máquina do usuário, uma opção válida seja uma aplicação dupla (web e desktop).

Comment: @JeffersonPedro, a minha resposta te dá o caminho das pedras para o seu problema. Caso não seja o suficiente para soluciona-lo, favor me passe mais informações sobre a sua aplicação que editarei minha resposta para melhor atente o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Se a aplicação for realizar vários requests para a aplicação web, o ideal é fazer um metodo no controller de autenticação que retorne um JWT(Json Web Token) e que você use esse token para fazer as requisições ao servidor sem precisar ficar dando um hit no banco a cada request para validar o usuário, você poderia armazenar esse token em alguma variável da aplicação desktop.

Caso você só precise validar esse usuário uma vez e receber os dados como grupo, email, nome, foto, etc, você pode criar um method no controller que receba usuario e senha, e se for válido retorne um json com os dados que você precisa, caso contrário retorne uma falha de login. Eu faria isso

Comment: A ideia é muito interessante, acho que vai me facilitar muito as coisas e ainda vou ter menos trabalho do que achava mediante essa sua explicação. Mas eu não tenho conhecimento nenhum sobre JWT. Você poderia, por gentileza, me indicar algum material e de preferência que tenha algum exemplo prático para eu estudar e entender como funciona as coisas direitinho?

Comment: Você pretende realizar várias requisições depois de efetuar o login ou apenas logar e retornar os dados do usuário? Se você quer apenas validar o login nem precisa usar JWT. Se você quiser usar JWT veja essa implementação: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/369657/Simple-Authentication-using-Jwt-in-Asp-Net-Web-Api     

Qualquer dúvida: daniel.alb.querque@gmail.com

Comment: A minha dificuldade é entender como autenticar um app desktop com o login vigente do app web. Basicamente o usuário vai acessar o site e quando for executar algumas determinadas operações, o site irá pedir pro usuário fazer pelo app desktop, quando o app desk for iniciado, ele faria a autenticação de usuário e senha baseado na autenticação feita na web, sem que o usuário refaça o login, quando terminar as operações no app desk a página web só receberia um comando de atualização para exibir os novos dados... Dá pra fazer dessa forma?

Comment: Você precisa arrumar uma forma de chamar a aplicação Desktop pela aplicação WEB, existem várias formas de fazer isso, você precisa arranjar uma forma de fazer isso enviando dados como parâmetro para o programa desktop, assim você nem precisa criar um form de login no desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Se a validação tem que ser com a "autenticação da aplicação desktop utilizando o login ativo da aplicação web" (conforme suas palavras) o mais correto é quando o usuário se autenticar na aplicação web esse login gerar um "token" de autenticação no sistema.

Aconselho ter uma tabela, por exemplo, "UsuarioToken" ao invés de guardar em "Session":

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsuarioToken] (
[Token]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[IdUsuario]          SMALLINT         NOT NULL,
[DataInicial]        DATETIME         DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[DataFinal]          DATETIME         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Token] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_UsuarioToken_Usuario] FOREIGN KEY ([IdUsuario]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Usuario] ([idUsuario]));
```

Ao "logar" na web, cria o token com a data de acesso (DataInicial). Ao "deslogar" inativa o token (DataFinal). Observe que a DataInicial tem como valor `DEFAULT` o `getdate()`, a `DataFinal` não, pois ela será a data e hora que o usuário "deslogar" da aplicação web. Será a `DataFinal` quando `NULL` que indicará se o token esta ativo ou não.

Com o token criado, agora vai depender da sua regra de negócio e o que mais for aplicável e/ou viável a sua situação, então o que vem abaixo é apenas exemplo/idéia:

Na aplicação desktop:

- Ao invés de ter um formulário com Usuário e Senha, teria um form para indicar a "chave de acesso", token criado no login web, que poderia ser enviado ao "cliente" via e-mail (e-mail este dos dados de cadastro do usuário). Se token ativo, ex.: `ValidarToken(Guid token)`, faz o processamento, se não retorna que token é inválido.
- Ter sim um form de login com usuário e senha para identifica e validar, a primeira vez, se o usuário (idUsuario) é cadastrado no sistema web, após isso verifica se token ("chave de acesso") esta associado ao usuário que esta logando e se token esta ativo no sistema web. Resumindo, você identifica uma vez se o usuário e senha é válido, se válido verifica se há uma "chave de acesso" ativa na aplicação web, se há armazena o token em uma variável no desktop e nos próximos processos que exija token, como ele já esta armazenado em memória, apenas verifica se o mesmo ainda esta ativo na aplicação web `ValidarToken(Guid token)`. Se não estiver, volta para o processo de login novamente.

Enfatizo as regras de segurança, pois o token deve ser invalidado após realizado todos os processos necessários no desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Para realizações de autenticações a forma mais elegante de fazer seria usando [Claims](http://www.devmedia.com.br/autenticacao-de-usuario-com-claims-e-asp-net-identity/33131).

Com Claims há uma fazibilidade para fazer o que você precisa, pois temos a possibilidade de autenticação de terceiros.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

O que você pode fazer também é separa a sua aplicação para que possua uma camada de [Serviço](http://www.macoratti.net/15/01/wcf_real.htm). E nela aplicar uma [funcionalidade de autenticação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb398990(v=vs.100).aspx).